# Which systemd target makes sure that all disks are ready?

Tags: systemd, boot, disk

`local-fs.target` seems only to check when all `mount` blocks are ready.

How can I ensure all disks are ready if there are many disks that didn't mount during/after boot?

Which target can be used to confirm all disks ( mount and didn't mount ) are ready to use/mount?

- `boot-complete.target`
- `basic.target`
- ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such target, because there is no way for systemd to know when it has indeed seen "all" disks. The difference is that all mounts that local-fs.target waits for are explicitly listed in /etc/fstab or elsewhere, while disks arrive out of nowhere as SATA and SAS and USB ports get enumerated; there's no definite list of them.

However, if you know exactly which disks you need to wait for, you can create your own target that depends on the `.device` units representing those disks. By default, both the basic /dev/sdX name and its various symlinks under /dev/disk/by-id will have corresponding .device units, so you can list them in After= for your custom target.

(Or even better, if there's a task that's done for each disk separately, then instead of having it wait for all disks you could create a templated service with instances for each disk – similar to how systemd-fsck@ runs separately for each device without waiting for "all of them".)